# Use 'If Exists' twice inside SQL Statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, exists

I'm trying to create a user when it doesn't exists. I's sounds very easy, but I need to control if something else exists. So I'm using twice a 'IF EXISTS'. Here is my code:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT userID 
               FROM UserTable 
               WHERE usernameID = (IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT usernameID 
                                                 FROM UsernameTable 
                                                 WHERE name = 'Martijn')
                                   BEGIN
                                       INSERT INTO  UsernameTable(name) 
                                       VALUES ('Martijn');
                                   END

                                   SELECT usernameID 
                                   FROM UsernameTable 
                                   WHERE name = 'Martijn';)
                   AND country = 'Netherlands')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO  UserTable(usernameID, country) 
    VALUES (1, 'Netherlands');
END
```

How can I fix this? Because MySQL doesn't like the `IF EXISTS` where I'm checking my `usernameID`. Do I need a procedure for this?

Comment: You need two commands - one for the user, and one for the user/country combination.

Comment: Is there no way to put everything in one SQL statment?

Comment: Create a simple schema of what you have. What version of MySQL are you working with? You may be able to use an upsert-ish syntax to accomplish what you need.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2017. The latest and newest version.

Comment: You've tagged MySQL in your post, but you say you're using a Microsoft SQL Server client. Are you using MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: You need to describe what you want to do.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server. I didn't know the different

Answer (score 0):

I searched for some solutions, but the best was using a `PROCEDURE`.
You can create multiple `IF EXISTS` inside your `PROCEDURE`.
I also was able to save my ID after creating a new user.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you should be able to do this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT userID FROM UserTable WHERE name = 'Martijn')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO  UsernameTable(name, country)
        VALUES ('Martijn', 'Netherlands');
END;
```

This is an attempt to understand your SQL code.  Insert "Martijn" into the table if no "Martijn" already exist.